# Запретить блоку вылезать за пределы экрана

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

Как запретить блоку вылезать за пределы экрана когда окно браузера сужено ? Нужно добавлять прокрутку и не перепозиционировать блок (menu).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что тебе мешает или кто, задать блоку определенную высоту и задать `overflow-y: scroll;`???

Comment: @Air Количество пунктов меню может быть разное. и когда экран развернуть в фулл скрин зачем там тогда прокрутка ? Использовать медиазапросы ?

Comment: Oleg Ovcharenko, да конечно  медиазапросы...  Ну вот когда задаешь ответ, сразу отмечай такие ключевые моменты...

Comment: @Air медиазапросы не пойдут...

Comment: Oleg Ovcharenko, будь другом, ну оформи вопрос нормально. Объясни суть, выложи код, что да как ты делал...  Ну ты же не в первый раз вопрос задаешь... После каждого коммента выясняется новые обстоятельства....

Comment: @Air По моему по картинке все ясно и понятно.

Comment: Я не могу по картинке определить почему медиазапросы не пойдут...

Comment: Возможно лучше использовать готовую библиотеку для этого, так как может быть много ситуаций когда меню будет некорректно отображено, а в библиотеке эти моменты скорее всего уже решены и не придётся изобретать велосипед. Например в bootstrap  используется `popper.js`

Comment: А вы сами меню показываете? Если это ваш кастомный JavaScript то просто верхнюю координату проверяете, если она меньше нуля ставите в 0. +`overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: Приведите ваш скрипт вывода меню.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Сдал по координатам. Спасибо. Мысли сошлись.

Comment: Я тогда ответом оформлю.

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы выводите меню, значит у вас есть какой-то скрипт который это делает и который указывает размеры и позицию окна меню.

Значит когда мы определяем координаты верхней точки меню мы смотрим, если эта координата меньше 0, тогда ставим её в 0.

При этом делаем стиль контейнера меню с `overflow-y: scroll`.